# First-order nonlinear ODE similar to Bernoulli DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know that the Bernoulli equations, i.e. equations in the form

$$ y' + p(x) y + q(x) y^{\alpha}=0$$

Can be [easily solved](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliDifferentialEquation.html) with a change of variables.

But what about equations in the form

$$y'  + q(x) y^{\alpha} + p(x)=0$$

Is there any easy way to solve those too?

Comment: It's worth noting that the Bernoulli differential equation can be solved even easier using a integrating factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case $\alpha=2$ is a [Ricati equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation), which in general cannot be solved explicitly in terms of the coefficients. It can be solved if one knows a particular solution. As far as I know, there are no methods of solution for $\alpha\ne2$ (except $\alpha=1$, of course.)